# XeLaTeX and Beamer miniframes not compatible

Tags: beamer, xetex, mini-frames

Recently (about 5 mins ago) I found that `miniframes`, a Beamer outer template, does not works properly if I compile the file by XeLaTeX.

To be specific, I tried to compile this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{1}\frame{2}\frame{3}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{4}\frame{5}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{6}\frame{7}\frame{8}\frame{9}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{10}\frame{11}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{12}\frame{13}\frame{14}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\frame{15}\frame{16}\frame{17}\frame{18}
\end{document}
```

with LaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and XeLaTeX separately. For the first two compilers the small circles are clickable while for the third compiler they are not. (The cursor does not become a hand while hovering). At the same time, three compilers produce clickable (sub)section titles.

I guess TeX.SX is not a good place to report bugs. But I am not sure if this is of XeLaTeX or of Beamer.

P.S. I am using OS X 10.11.1 and MacTeX and I just synced my packages.

Comment: An example of code?

Comment: @egreg Yes, the code in [this page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mini-frames/info) can reproduce my problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a bug in the XeTeX driver for `hyperref`.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296332/beamer-my-subsection-bullets-in-navigation-bar-doesnt-jump-by-clicking-when-i

Comment: related bug report: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/332

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/332#issuecomment-300718711 the problem seems to be, that with xelatex non-text hyperlinks do not work - the usual miniframe bullet is a circle drawn with `pgf`, so non-text.

A workaround could be to place some text behind the circle of the miniframe, which thus becomes clickable.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current section}
{%
  \visible<0>{\resizebox{0.1cm}{0.1cm}{o}}\kern-0.1cm%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}
{%
  \visible<0>{\resizebox{0.1cm}{0.1cm}{o}}\kern-0.1cm%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{1}\frame{2}\frame{3}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{4}\frame{5}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{6}\frame{7}\frame{8}\frame{9}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{10}\frame{11}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{12}\frame{13}\frame{14}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\frame{15}\frame{16}\frame{17}\frame{18}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will `\only<0>{o}` do the trick?

Comment: @Symbol1 Nice Idea! For some problems with the spacing, I went for `\visible<0>`.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, only for me the `o` and the `pgfpicture` were slightly misaligned, which didn't look good. I added another workaround by using the background color of the top bar as color for the `o`: `\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette quaternary}o`.