# Beamer: My subsection bullets in navigation bar doesn't jump by clicking when I use XeLaTeX, though the pdfLaTeX can render it normally

Tags: beamer, xetex, cjk, navigation, xecjk

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\title{\LaTeX~\textsc{Beamer}Testing}
\author{Testname}
\institute{Testing University}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%%---------------------------
\begin{document}

\section*{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{SecA}\subsection{sub1}\frame{Hello01}\subsection{sub2}\frame{Hello02}\subsection{sub3}\frame{Hello03}
\section{SecB}\subsection{sub1}\frame{Hello04}\subsection{sub2}\frame{Hello05}\subsection{sub3}\frame{Hello06}
\section{SecC}\subsection{sub1}\frame{Hello07}\subsection{sub2}\frame{Hello08}\subsection{sub3}\frame{Hello09}
\section{SecD}\subsection{sub1}\frame{Hello10}\subsection{sub2}\frame{Hello11}\subsection{sub3}\frame{Hello12}
\section{SecE}\subsection{sub1}\frame{Hello13}\subsection{sub2}\frame{Hello14}\subsection{sub3}\frame{Hello15}
\section{SecF}\subsection{sub1}\frame{Hello16}\subsection{sub2}\frame{Hello17}\subsection{sub3}\frame{Hello18}
\section{SecG}\subsection{sub1}\frame{Hello19}\subsection{sub2}\frame{Hello20}\subsection{sub3}\frame{Hello21}
\end{document}
```

When I render this via pdfLaTeX, everything go right. But when I choose XeLaTeX, those subsection bullets in navigation bar doesn't have a hyperlink in them. I really need to use XeLaTeX for my BEAMER, because a xeCJK package has a wonderful effect in my work, and it only works in xeLaTeX.

I want the bullet hyperlink be normal in xeLaTeX just as in pdf LaTeX.

Comment: I don't know if you can use it with `xeCJK` but hyperlinks also work with `LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: related bug report: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/332