# The hyperlinks of Navigation's “section head” does not work under "xelatex"

Tags: beamer, navigation, hyperlink

Basic info:

- OS version: Windows 10
- TeX version: TeX Live 2019
- Editor: TeXstudio 2.12.14

Detailed issue:

When under "pdflatex", the hyperlink of “section head” of the Mini Frame Navigation works (clickable).

However, when under "xelatex", the hyperlink of “section head” of the Mini Frame Navigation does not works (non clickable).

Such as the following picture:

[image: ytWkkD.md.jpg]

**How to fix this?**

BTW, my test code is:

```
%! Tex program = pdflatex or xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8,10pt]{beamer}


\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamerfont{font of headline by me}{size*={6}{1}}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}% 
{   
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{font of headline by me}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}



\begin{document}

\section{Sec}

\subsection{subSec1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle of subSec1} 
Hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle of subSec1} 
Hello
\end{frame}


\subsection{subSec2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle of subSec2} 
Hello
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in commit [a10b34f56937e239fa5342b21e61576e0e1e0757](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/a10b34f56937e239fa5342b21e61576e0e1e0757) and is included in beamer v3.65 or newer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the same issue here

[XeLaTeX and Beamer miniframes not compatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274828)

My issue can be closed :)

Comment: Hm, possible that this is now fixable,  xdvipdfmx has been improved here.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer  Do you have a link? I found that the solution in  
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274828/   is not very perfect~

Comment: I added a comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344272/2388